# openvpn via command line: permission denied to update resolv.conf

Tags: bash, openvpn, resolvconf

This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854704/openvpn-dns-use-update-resolv-conf-sh-failed-permission-denied), but I am not proficient enough in networking matters to tell for sure.

I use a VPN service named Cyberghost to stay private on the internet. After facing DNS leaks when using `network-manager` I tried using the command line and implement fixes promoted online. Aparantly `block-outside-dns` works on windows only. Therefore I followed [this tutorial](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html) and added the lines

```
script-security 2
up /etc/resolv.conf
down /etc/resolv.conf
```

to the .ovpn file provided by cyberghost.

When trying to connect using

```
sudo openvpn --config /home/username/CG/DE/DE.ovpn
```

however I get the following error:

```
Options error: --up script fails with '/etc/resolv.conf': Permission denied
Options error: Please correct this error.
Use --help for more information.
```

Connecting without the up and down command works fine but causes dns leaks. I do not encounter problems manually editing `resolv.conf` using sudo privilleges therefore I am unsure why openvpn should lack the permission to do so.

Thank you for your thoughts and your help,

Alex

---

System: Kubuntu 17.04

openvpn 2.4.0-4ubuntu1.3

The full .ovpn-file is as follows:

```
client

remote 1-de.cg-dialup.net 443

dev tun 

proto udp

auth-user-pass /home/username/CG/DE/auth.txt




resolv-retry infinite 

redirect-gateway def1

persist-key

persist-tun

nobind

cipher AES-256-CBC

auth MD5

ping 5

ping-exit 60

ping-timer-rem

explicit-exit-notify 2

script-security 2

remote-cert-tls server

route-delay 5

tun-mtu 1500 

fragment 1300

mssfix 1300

verb 4

comp-lzo


ca /home/username/CG/DE/ca.crt

cert /home/username/CG/DE/client.crt

key /home/username/CG/DE/client.key

script-security 2
up /etc/resolv.conf
down /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether or not this is what you really want or need to do, this bit here:

```
up /etc/resolv.conf
down /etc/resolv.conf
```

is not how this functionality works. Rather, the `openvpn-systemd-resolved` package dynamically updates the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, by specifying an executable script after the `up` and `down` in your openvpn client conf (as per the linked (and incomplete!) "tutorial"). But also, note there are different versions of this functionality; [later versions use dbus](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved), which I'm referencing; the [previous version](https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf) just used scripts & temp files. So that's why there's some inconsistency across articles/docs/tutorials.

So, assuming this package is installed (either via `apt-get` or `apt`):

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn-systemd-resolved
```

and verifying the service is running (if not: enable it and start it manually):

```
sudo service systemd-resolved status
```

then, there should be a script installed as `/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` (or possibly in `/etc/openvpn/scripts/` in other distributions) that *modifies* the `/etc/resolv.conf` for you.

So your openvpn client conf (which on non-windows clients should by convention have a "`.conf`" suffix, and they'll automatically be read if in `/etc/openvpn`; but on windows they typically use `.ovpn` for proper file association w/ openvpn) -- the openvpn client conf would contain, for example,

```
script-security 2
setenv PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
up /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down /etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved
down-pre
```

Then you'll noticed that it's the `/etc/openvpn/update-systemd-resolved` script that needs to be executable (it is by default), and `/etc/resolv.conf` will  be a simple text file that is then updated with correct `domain`, `nameserver`, `search` entries (it's *not* an executable script).

The last element to tie tis together is to modify `/etc/nsswitch.conf`  to contain something like the following (replacing the existing `hosts:` entry):

```
# Use systemd-resolved first, then fall back to /etc/resolv.conf
hosts: files resolve dns myhostname
```

See the [linked update-systemd-resolved github page](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved) for details and options.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is running

```
sudo -s
```

Then running

```
openvpn --config file.ovpn
```

If that doesn't work try running

```
sudo chown root /etc/resolv.conf
```

or

```
sudo chown $USER /etc/resolv.conf
```

and as a last resort

```
sudo chmod 777 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Only use `chmod 777` if nothing else works, as it can cause a security hole.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! None of your safe methods worked, so I checked what chmod my resolv.conf has so I can revert the changes later. To my astonishment however, it already had 777. I executed your command anyway, unfortunately this did not help :/

I now changed my resolv.conf back to the default 644 for the time being